# Multiple HTML links to specific pages in PDF

Tags: html, pdf

I have created a sort of table of content in html that link to specific page into pdf using #page=n and it works fine if i have 1 link for 1 pdf.

The problem comes when i have multiple link to the same pdf.
ie:

- href="001.pdf#page=10"
- href="001.pdf#page=20"
- href="001.pdf#page=30"

The first time it works fine and open the pdf at the right page, then if i use others link with the pdf opne, the page didn't change.
There is a workaround for this?

---

Thanks for the first answer. You right, i've forgot some informations. 
The final output have to be cross-browsers.

This is my test code with random online pdf:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<a href="https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_tutorial.pdf#page=5" target="PDFcontent">link 001</a>
<a href="https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_tutorial.pdf#page=10" target="PDFcontent">link 002</a>
<a href="https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_tutorial.pdf#page=15" target="PDFcontent">link 003</a>
<a href="https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_tutorial.pdf#page=20" target="PDFcontent">link 004</a>
<a href="https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_tutorial.pdf#page=25" target="PDFcontent">link 005</a>
<iframe style="height:800px; width:800px;"  name="PDFcontent" src="http://www.naplesip.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/pdf-logo.png"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried to used it on jsfiddle but does not work. Instead it work on browsers (firefox/chrome/edge/ie).

Answer (score 0):

There is not much background information about how you are opening the PDF, what browser you are using, and how you use the other links. I will answer as well as I can in a general way.

Opening PDFs into a desktop program might accept your page anchor tag and jump to the requested page upon opening a PDF, but opening the same document again (while it is still open) will result in the system simply switching your active application to the one with the PDF open.

If you first close the document, then open another page, I suspect it would work, unless settings in your PDF reader are remembering the previous page.

This behaviour is something you have little control over on your own computer, and no control over on anyone else's so you might have to come up with an alternative.

Comment: Thanks, i've added some information about my problem.